# Having trouble with z-index and position absolute divs

Tags: css, position, z-index

I have tried to add `position:relative` and `z-index:1000` to my `ul` navigation elements but it continues to display behind the logo and content which is set to position relative.

I found a small script which positions all the ul elements to 1000 and that did not work either.

Example: http://islands.kellykruschel.com/directory/accommodations/

Hover over Things to Do >> Outdoor Sports

Any solutions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `#topbar` add this:

```
#topbar{
z-index: 1000;
}
```

This should make it sit on top of the logo. It works in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Add  `#topbar z-index;`

```
#topbar{
z-index:999;
}
```